# Drive API download without login

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

I'm currently developing an application that acts as a file service for clients. The application is connected to one Google account that it retrieves files from. I've stored the access and refresh tokens for this account and have authorized everything necessary.

We're using Drive as a storage solution and we're giving clients access to certain folders within our Drive account through our application. From our application they can see a list of files and then download those files. The problem is that the standard Drive download methods all require that the user is logged into to a Google account and if they aren't it redirects them to a login page. Once they're logged in to Google the download works, but we need it to work without them being logged in to Google.

Is there any way around this? I've tried several ways to get around it (manual authorized cURL requests, authorized php-api httpRequests, etc) but haven't gotten anything to work.

Comment: What is "the standard Drive download methods"? You're using PHP. So use PHP to get the file contents. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#fetching_file_metadata_and_content_from_google_drive) is an example. Or did you try that already?

Comment: [These](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_files_in_a_browser) are the "standard download methods" which includes a version of what you linked to. (Which btw is documentation for using an example app, not for standard usage) And yes, it returns a 302 status code. And when I try doing it manually with cURL I get a 401 status code.

Comment: Yep. You need to be logged in to get to the Google documents. That's why i thought the only way was using `Google_HttpRequest` and `getResponseBody` (per example, i didn't even use $app) yourself in php and redirecting your output to the user. Works here with a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i did with an example php. (All the authentication stuff is stripped out.)

```
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$url="the_url_to_your_document_according_to_$service->files->listFiles";
$request = new Google_HttpRequest($url);
$response = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);
$content = $response->getResponseBody();
```

Now you can pipe `$content` to the user (if there are no errors of course).

**EDIT**: I did some testing and you **can** download directly with Curl authentication. If you get a 401 error you are using an access token which expired. Just get a new one (new login with authentication) and do a curl directly (within 3600 or 1800 seconds):

```
curl -o testfile -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.yournewone' 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/xxx'
```

It worked for me. You can use the "downloadUrl" for this according to [that page](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads). No need to use getWebContentLink.

If you want long term tokens you need to request a "Refresh token". You can find some information on [this page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices). There are some limits in numbers to request these mentioned on that page at the bottom.

**EDIT #2**: Just did another test. I could download directly from the downloadUrl by adding `&access_token=ya29.xxxxxxxxxx`. 'ya29.xxxxxxxxxx' being your latest access_token. No need for authentication via Curl and user does not have to be logged in Google if you use downloadUrl instead of getting a WebContentLink (only a recent access_token is needed). So i could set this link on a page where everybody could download the file(s) (for about half an hour after which the links/access_token needs to be refreshed)

Comment: It appears that my token had expired. The weird part is that the thing the API wouldn't do was download. I could still list files and get their meta info. 

I ended up using the solution you suggested in edit #2.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that too. In some weird way the access_token does work on some operation (as listing files and logging in) but gives an error on downloading. I think they do give an expire tag when getting the token but why it keeps working on 'listfiles' is beyond me. Glad it works now for you.